# Is NSNotificationCenter an implementation of a PubSub model?

Tags: pubsub

I am trying to understand the subtleties of Publisher-subscriber and similar notification mechanisms. I was checking Cocoa NSNotificationCenter, but it's unclear to me if it can be defined as a PubSub, strictly speaking.

Is NSNotificationCenter a PubSub?

Comment: [This article](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html) says: "when registering for a notification, you can specify a specific broadcaster object," which seems to suggest a Publisher/Subscriber model.

Comment: See also https://objcsharp.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/why-nsnotificationcenter-is-bad/

Comment: In short: yes, it's a PubSub.